# What strategy to manage EF core change tracker when a large number of entities are tracked

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core

We are using entity framework core 6 in an ASP.net core accounting software application.

A few operation consist of importing a large number of different entities in the database (these are backup restore process and XML import from another software). The amount of data in these source files can be quite large (several ten of thousands of entities).

Since the number of entities is too large to handle in a single transaction, we have a batching system that will call "SaveChanges" on the db context every few hundreds inserts (otherwise, the final "SaveChanges" simply wouldn't work)

We're running into a performance problem: when the change tracker contains many entities (a few thousands or more), every call to DetectChanges takes a loooooong time (several seconds)  and so the whol import process is becomming almost exponentially slower as the dataset size grows.

We are experimenting with the possibility of create new, short-lived context to save some of the more numerous entities instead of loading the in the initial db context but that is a process that is rather hard to code properly: there are many object that we need to copy (in part or in full) and pass to the calling context to be able to rebuild the data structure properly.

So, I was wondering if there was another approach. Maybe a way to tell the change tracger that a set of entities should be kep around for reference but not to be serialized anymore (and, of course, skipped by the change detection process).

**Edit** I was asked for a specific business case so here it is: accounting data is stored per fiscal year.

Each fiscal year contains the data itself but also all the configuration options necessary for the software to work. This data is actually a rather complex set of relationships: accounts contains reference to tax templates (to be used when creating entry line for this account) which themselves contains several references to accounts (for referencing which accounts should be used to create entry lines for recording the tax amount). There are many such circular relationships in the model.

The load process therefore need to load the accounts first and record, for each one, what tax template it references. Then we load the taxe templates, fill in the references to the accounts and then have to process the accounts again to enter the ID of the newly created taxes.

We're using an ORM because the data model is defined by the class model: saving data directly to the database certainly would be possible but every time we would change the model, we'd had to manually adjust all these methodes as well: I'm trying to limit the number of ways my (small) team can shoot themselves in the foot when improving out model (whihc is evolving fast) and having a single reference for the data model seems like the way to go.

Comment: *You're doing it wrong.* ORM tools like Entity Framework aren't meant for ETL jobs. They're *only* meant to load graphs of related objects to give applications the illusion they work with in-memory objects. That's it. Nothing more. If you try to use ORMs for anything else the illusion breaks. Especially for ETL jobs where there are no Objects, only Extractions, Transformations and Loading operations on Rows.

Comment: After batch call `context.ChangeTracker.Clear()`

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv this is like applying Band-Aid to a gunshot wound. Why cache the data inside a DbContext in the first place? Why detect changes when you already know what these are? Why try to map objects when you only need to *insert* rows?

Comment: @Stephane What are you trying to do? Explain the actual business problem, not how you think it can be solved using an ORM. That's simply the wrong tool and even the wrong architecture. Most databases offer a way to bulk import data programmatically, eg SQL Server has SqlBulkCopy. MySqlConnector has an equivalent class. Instead of executing one INSERT per object, ADO.NET sends a stream of data to the server that's inserted using minimal logging, in a way similar to `BULK INSERT` or `COPY` in MySQL/PostgreSQL

Comment: When you have a ton of data you can't just load everything into memory either. ETL jobs use a *pipeline* of processing steps that work on a stream or objects/rows. This way you can work with far more data than RAM allows.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, you don't know on which stage his project. I agree that EF is not for ETL jobs. But rewriting everything can be not an option at all. Pointed to method which resets `ChangeTracker` state.

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, I do appreciate them all. To answer a few Qs: the projet is already in production but the data model is really complex because we're porting an older application that has been developped in the last 35 years (!) and so it has a rather complex data structure.

Comment: If there is a better way that would require us to rewrite the import code, we would certainly consider it as long as it doesn't require us to redefine the data model in a separate way (for instance, I would not consider manually writing SQL statements for saving entities to te database)